Publish an Array of Values as Wrench Message in ROS2 and Python
I'm using a geometry wrench message, and I would like to send 4 values at each force and torque axis. I tried something like this:
        msg.force.x = [0.0]*4
        msg.force.y = [0.0]*4
        msg.force.z = [0.0]*4
        msg.torque.x = [0.0]*4
        msg.torque.y = [0.0]*4
        msg.torque.z = [0.0]*4

But I get this error:
>>AssertionError: The 'x' field must be of type 'float' 

Is there a way to send such an array, or a multiple data to wrench message, without creating my own message?

I don't think it is possible: the types of the fields in a message are hard-coded in its .msg definition and the C++ interfaces are generated once at message compilation.
Would still require a custom message but the least effort I think of would be an array of geometry_msgs/Wrench Messages... (or hack by using an existing message with an array like Polygon, but not a good practice)
